# JQuery, AJAX, запрос POST, параметры запроса пусты

Tags: jquery, ajax

Пытаюсь отправить POST-запрос через AJAX с помощью jQuery (версия - 2.1.1):

```
    function deleteItem(id) {
        alert("Deleting " + id);
        var dataString = JSON.stringify('{\"id\": \"' + id + '\"}');
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/delete_item",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: dataString,
            contentType: 'application/json',
                mimeType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data) {
                    var txt = data;
                    $('#message').html(txt);
                },
            error: function(data, status, err) {
                $('#message').html(err);
            }
        });
    }
```

Web-приложение - на Spring MVC. Метод контроллера вызывается успешно, но в запросе отсутствуют параметры.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/delete_item", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String ajaxDelete(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Enumeration<String> en = request.getParameterNames();
        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            String pname = en.nextElement();
            System.out.println("//// " + pname);
        }
        String idStr = request.getParameter("id");
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt(idStr);
//...
```

Пробовал сначала без JSON.stringify, то же самое.
Почему теряется параметр запроса? Что не так?

Comment: data: {"id": id},

Comment: Хорошее уточнение, но это тоже не помогло. Результат абсолютно тот же самый.